# Globally manage unexpected exception in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, exception

I'm coming at the end of the development of my application.

Everything is working fine, but if once somebody got an unexpected exception, I would like to be able to:

1. Redirect him to a user-friendly page explaining that we got a problem.(Specifying a controller/action)
2. Log every information of the stack trace, current controller/action, parameter, session data, ...

What is the best way to do it with asp.net MVC?

**EDIT**

In complement of the great answer:
I integrated elmah like described here: http://joel.net/logging-errors-with-elmah-in-asp.net-mvc-3--part-1--setup
And then I specified some custom error page. So now I've all I need!

Comment: May this article helps you http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use "Elmah"  http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

This package is a godsend - does exactly what is shown on the box, with close to ZERO changes to your source code.

It is also available via NuGet at http://nuget.org/packages/elmah

Comment: Elmah works flawlessly with MVC .... you may have to provide an extra route for the "Web based" display - but I use in all MVC projects with no problems whatsoever.

Comment: I'm following this tutorial to try to use it: http://joel.net/logging-errors-with-elmah-in-asp.net-mvc-3--part-1--setup . I got my exception logged, but I my users still see the exception page when I'm doing a throw new Exception();

Comment: I think that would be more to do with your web.config "CustomErrors" setting rather than Elmah.

Comment: I just ran into trouble: Seems that I need different dll for elmah in 64 bits and elmah in 32 bits, and I cannot do this for now because we are all using the visual studio development server(which runs only in 32 bits). Any workaround?

Comment: That surprises me ... I run full x64 for development (of course VStudio is only a 32bit app) ... but I have had no similar problems :(

Comment: Which elmah version did you take? The 32bits or the 64 bits?

Answer (score 2):

Use action filters.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gduthie/archive/2011/03/17/get-to-know-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-handleerror.aspx

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. But with this I see how to display a custom error, but I don't see how: Have this custom error globaly, without having to put this new action filter on each of my 200+ actions, and how to log those exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch errors in the global.asax. There is a method `protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` where you can do what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/), neat and easy to use. Starter version available to use after free registration. NuGet package also available http://nuget.org/packages/PostSharp